# how to create android intent filter without hyperlink

Tags: android, intentfilter, whatsapp

I have tried setting intent filter as http://myapp.com which works well if there is a hyperlink link of this type. Another is myapp:// and I have only managed to get this to work by redirecting from a webpage. Eg. Localhost/redirect.jsp which redirects to myapp://etc

How and where else can I use myapp://etc ? Specifically in messaging app such as whatsapp, line, etc. In android, myapp://etc are not clickable.

Comment: whatsapp doesn't know the existence of myapp://etc so the line is not clickable. It's not recognized as a "standard" protocol. You should continue using http://myapp.com

Comment: Its not only whatsapp. Other apps also can't recognize myapp://etc  is this the behavior of android because iOS is able to do so, eg. Whatsapp://

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
TextView v = new TextView(this);
v.setTextSize(24);
v.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
ssb.append("this is my ");
int start = ssb.length();
ssb.append("app");
int end = ssb.length();
ssb.append(" just use it!");

URLSpan span = new URLSpan("myapp://some.host");
ssb.setSpan(span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
v.setText(ssb);

setContentView(v);
```

or use one of Linkify.addLinks() method to add your myapp://etc links

actifity declaration in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyAppActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Hi, that is for usage in my app instead of other apps?

Comment: for your app, but works with any app that creates URLSpans with your myapp:// scheme

Comment: that's not a solution. Other apps can't recognize custom protocols not standardized.

Comment: because Linkify doesnt recognize custom schemes, you have to use addLinks with scheme and pattern params